# How to db.Find(id) without entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been able to do a lot of cool stuff with my first MVC project. However, I am not a trained programmer so I sometimes get stuck on simple things. I got everything working using entity framework with a predefined list of database tables, but my application needs to automatically use new tables as they are generated so I decided to use a call function instead of entity. Pages that list the database items are working, but I am having trouble with the pages that display details for a specific item. I'm not sure how to pass in the ID and then display info for that ID...

The entity way

```
public ActionResult Summary(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        ixoc_G0000102_RunSummary ixoc_G0000102_RunSummary = db.ixoc_G0000102_RunSummary.Find(id);
        if (ixoc_G0000102_RunSummary == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ixoc_G0000102_RunSummary);
    }
```

The new way

```
public ActionResult Summary(string id)
    {
        if (Session["LoggedUser"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            UserData userd = (UserData)Session["LoggedUser"];
            CustomerData customerd = (CustomerData)Session["LoggedCustomer"];
            List<NodeInfo> nodes = siteContext.siServerConnect.GetNodes(customerd.ixguid, customerd.AccessLevel);
            nodes = nodes.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
            string[] online = siteContext.siServerConnect.GetLiveNodesFromServer();

            List<string> nodeNames = new List<string>();
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan periodToQuery = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime startTime = endTime - periodToQuery;

            foreach (NodeInfo n in nodes)
            {
                nodeNames.Add(n.name);
            }

            List<AverageNodeValues> runs = siteContext.siServerConnect.GetRuns(nodeNames, startTime, endTime);
            runs = runs.Find(id);
            DataWrapper wrapper = new DataWrapper(nodes, online, runs);
            return View(wrapper);
        }
    }
```

There is something wrong with the Find(id) part, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about this part:

```
List<AverageNodeValues> runs = siteContext.siServerConnect.GetRuns(nodeNames, startTime, endTime);
runs = runs.Find(id);
```

I'm guessing you are trying to find a specific `AverageNodeValues` object by its `Id`. You'll need to do something like (not knowing what that object properties are) `run = runs.Where(x => x.Id == id)` if you are just trying to limit the first query, but you could do that as `List<AverageNodeValues> runs = siteContext.siServerConnect.GetRuns(nodeNames, startTime, endTime).Where(.....)` inline.

If you are just trying to get a single entity, then use either `SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)` or `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [List<>.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) , it takes a predicate in order to find an item e.g.

`runs = runs.Find(item => return item.id == id);`

Or you could use the LINQ extension methods such as [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx)

`runs = runs.SingleOrDefault(item => return item.id == id);`

Which will return the single item that matches the `id`, or `NULL` if no item is found. Overall I suggest using the LINQ methods, as they will be the more commonly used methods of finding items in collections e.g. `List<T>`.

Try that, see if it works.